# A list of known string issues in VC++ 6.0

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6, cstring

I am looking for some list containing all string related issues in VC++ 6.0 which are fixed in later service packs such as [this one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193100). Can anyone please help me on this regard?

The reason for my search is this: We face some string related issues in our VC++ 6.0 based product. I am looking for other potential issues.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not enough info what the issue is

Answer (score 1):

You can seach MSDN knowledge base, [troubleshooting and support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa570318.aspx).

For example, a [search with CString keyword](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-us/?query=cstring&refinement=108) will reveal many bug fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I realise it can be a pain to download all of the service packs, but you should just be running with all SP's installed anyway.

The service packs have release notes, that are linked to from here....

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/194022